# ASP.Net MVC Upload file to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to insert a file into a database and I have this code in my controller :

```
public ActionResult Create(CertificationViewModel vm, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try 
    {
        CertificationDetail ds = new CertificationDetail();

        if(ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            ds.CertificationTypeId = vm.CertificationTypeId;
            ds.StatusId = vm.StatusId;
            ds.Result = vm.Result;
            vm.FileName = file.FileName;
            ds.pdf = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(vm.pdf, 0, file.ContentLength);
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

My file in database is a `VarBinary(3600)` and my file in the model is a `byte[].

When I try to insert something into the database, it becomes null, it first goes to a DAL to get the confirmation and then yes, it is inserted into the database.

Can someone detect any error in my code?

Comment: where is your inserting logic to database?

Comment: what comes as `null` and where ? What is your expected behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code is the same code you have, and your `CertificationDetail` class is your database model, then you have a logic error when calling `InputStream.Read`.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) for `InputStream.Read` for the first parameter:

> buffer
>   Type: System.Byte[]
>
> An array of bytes. When this method returns, the buffer contains the specified byte array with the values between offset and (offset +
>   count - 1) replaced by the bytes read from the current source.

So, essentially, you are overwriting the buffer array in the ViewModel, but not in the `CertificationDetail` class. You need to set the first parameter of `InputStream.Read` to whatever `byte[]` that you want to save the bytes in to.

Change your `InputStream.Read` call to the following: `file.InputStream.Read(ds.pdf, 0, file.ContentLength)`, and that should fix the save into the database if the `CertificationDetail` is what you use to save into the database.